# Illegal datatype context

Tags: haskell

I have to do some exercises on BST and I need to use this implementation for the tree:

```
data ( Ord a , Show a , Read a ) => BST a = Void | Node {
  val :: a ,
  left , right :: BST a
  } 
   deriving ( Eq , Ord , Read , Show )
```

But the compiler gives me:

```
Illegal datatype context (use DatatypeContexts): (Ord a,
                                                      Show a,
                                                      Read a) =>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: That sounds very old fashioned. Just remove the `( Ord a , Show a , Read a ) =>` part and you'll be fine.

Comment: If you were given this definition (by a teacher, or a book or tutorial you're following), and they didn't mention anything about enabling the `DatatypeContexts` extension, then it means they were expecting you to be using an older version of GHC. There might be other inconsistencies that you'll bump into, unless you can find out what version of GHC they were expecting and install that (or possibly better, find newer learning materials).

Comment: @Ben, Hugs is another possibility. I think there's one person who was teaching with it a couple years ago; he may still be doing so for all I know.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah, that may well be it. Whether it's old GHC or Hugs or something else though, my main point was the apparent mismatch between where the exercises came from and the OP's Haskell install, if the OP gets the error about `DatatypeContexts` being off from code they were given that obviously assumes it's on. They're likely to encounter other differences and difficulties if they're using a version of Haskell quite different from the one expected by their learning environment, so they should probably find out about it.

Answer (score 5):

Data type contexts are generally considered useless, and were for this reason removed from standard Haskell at some point. (There hasn't been an official standard document since 2010, which still contained them, but GHC which is the de-facto standard now does not allow them by default anymore.)

These contexts don't really accomplish anything, except forcing anybody who mentions `BST a` to also require `Ord a, Show a, Read a` – but these constraints could not actually be *used* then anywhere else. So, everything you could do with your constrained version, can also be done with the simpler

```
data BST a = Void
           | Node { val :: a, left, right :: BST a } 
   deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

Note that the derived e.g. `Ord` instance will automatically add `Ord a` to its context, but without also requiring `Read a`.

Any function you define for this datatype may also need to impose some of the constraints, but it will need only those that are actually needed for the implementation, not indiscriminately *all* of them.